# Add ActionMailer with multiple SMTP servers in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, actionmailer, mailer

I have a need to use two different smtp servers in a Rails application. It appears that the way ActionMailer is constructed, it is not possible to have different smtp_settings for a subclass. Does anyone have a solution/plugin for something like this?

Ideally I would like to have

If the user entered smtp details has some error with password then other default smtp should be used in the application to send the mail to the customer.

Can anyone suggest me?

Comment: You can override the default configuration at run time:  https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#sending-emails-with-dynamic-delivery-options

Comment: I need both the smtp details at run time. Because when the one fails it should delivery from other smtp settings.